# Can I redirect the standard output from a process started with apr_proc_create to an in-memory stream?

Tags: c++, apr

I'm using the Apache Portable Runtime function `apr_proc_create` to start a child process and capture its standard output. I'm currently redirecting the output to a temporary file (much like [the APR test case](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/test/testproc.c)), and then reading the file after the process exits. I would like to avoid the disk access if I can, and redirect the output directly to an in-memory stream.

*So:*

**Can I redirect the standard output from a process started with apr_proc_create to an in-memory stream?**